# Can I remove the labels from ICs?

Tags: integrated-circuit, obfuscation

In [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100078/how-can-i-go-about-obfuscating-the-design-of-my-circuits-and-embedded-controls) I asked about ways one might obfuscate the design of a system, to prevent unauthorized cloning. One suggestion was that IC manufacturers are often willing to put custom labels on their chips. The idea is interesting, but my quantities are low enough that this would not be cost-effective. How might one remove or otherwise render unreadable the labels on ICs?

Comment: Keep in mind that anything you do to increase your cost will increase your sell price, which gives a even bigger margin for the cloners to make money, making it more likely the product will be cloned.

Comment: @OlinLathrop True, but the cloners can sell it cheaper than we can under any circumstances. At our volumes, everything is hand-built. It's amazing what undercutting you can do when labor is practically free.

Comment: @StephenCollings It doesn't help when the exact same parts are available to competitors for a fraction of the price, and lower quality for even less.

Comment: If the cloners can sell it a large amount cheaper, then you need better manufacturing.

Comment: Automation is not practical at our volumes, and we're not willing to off-shore the manufacturing.

Comment: Are you using any microcontrollers in the design?  If so, I'd just secure the software with the micro's lock fuse (or whatever) and call it good.  If someone really wants to reverse engineer your circuit, they will.  Or pot the thing.

Comment: If you have low volumes and low prices, it's not worthwhile to clone your product. If you have low volume and high prices, then you are in the business of selling service contracts anyway.

Comment: Silego greenpak is filthy cheap, and gives you programmable logic, comparators, voltage reference, letting you hide part of a simple analog design. Very easy to design. Spiteful little package. https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/configurable-mixed-signal

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Grinding or other abrasives is the only reliable method. I think I've seen machines that will do this for DIP components.

A dedicated reverse-engineering person can probably guess the part from the pinout, surrounding circuit, and package or simply have the epoxy removed and look at the identification numbers on the die under a microscope, so it only goes so far.

In my (somewhat) humble opinion, hiding the numbers on chips is kind of a red flag that the product is really easy to clone, has nothing proprietary in it, and is being sold for a very healthy margin, but perhaps that's just me. You won't find top tier manufacturers doing it.

You could always incorporate one of [these](http://www.topline.tv/drawings/pdf/qfp/TQFP32T19.7.pdf) chips.

Comment: I'm impressed, your description of our product is pretty much perfect.

Comment: Don't forget that many chips have identification on the bottom side too.

Comment: I did not understand the last line. What is that chip? How is it related to the answer? My guess is that you are suggesting use of dummy components that are there just to obscure the design or to make the design seem complex/expensive so that people don't even think of reverse engineering it.

Comment: @Dojo It's a dummy non-functional part with many pins that may appear complex, to contain IP such as firmware etc.

Comment: I think *exactly* the same thing `hiding the numbers on chips is kind of a red flag that the product is really easy to clone, has nothing proprietary in it, and is being sold for a very healthy margin`

Comment: Top-tier manufacturers do it, but instead of erasing markings, they request the chip manufacturer to put other markings. This can be done when ordering large quantities (my previous company was doing it) and this is common practice.

Comment: @Damien I used to see house numbers a lot, but it does not seem to be very  common  these days and I don't really see the benefit in paying extra to have your own number scheme. Did you get some inkling of *why* they thought it desirable or necessary?

Comment: To make copying more difficult. If you look at channels like EEVBlogs that disassemble circuits, it's very common to have custom markings that leads to nothing. It doesn't necessarily means it's custom ASIC, most of the time they just relabel. In my previous company they relabel only for the purpose of hiding which component is actually used. And it worked, 2 companies are actively trying to copy the system for about 10 years and they still haven't got it right.

Comment: @Damien Okay. I've mostly seen it in the context of automotive and similar large customers who were probably not worried about copying at all.

Comment: Yes, I guess in automotive, electronics isn't really the strongest worrying point of IP protection, except perhaps Tesla. We are more in the smaller, specific market related to specific measurement, thus smaller company size that doesn't have millions to reverse engineer products. And in the likes of Sony (cameras, PlayStations, and so forth), they will do custom ASICs anyways. Marking erasing makes sense mostly to small/mid-sized companies.

Answer (score 7):

A little sandpaper will take the laser-etched marking off most ICs.  (The laser markings are hard to read in the best of circumstances, so it doesn't take much scuffing to render it illegible.)

That said, if your IC is at all popular, it won't obscure much.  The supply pin locations are one giveaway, and the rest of the circuit (unless it's really novel) give a pretty clear indication to an experienced observer.

On the other hand, you just need to make it more of a pain to reverse-engineer than to redesign from scratch.

Comment: The last point is a good one - especially because re-design will likely only be a re-implementation to an established requirement.  Sometimes just figuring out *what it should do* consumes a lot more development time than actually implementing any particular one the various functionalities it is given on the way to being an actual product.

Comment: I hate to say this, but misleading statements in the specifications and descriptions may be helpful. Of course you have to be careful not to mislead your customers to their detriment or there may be consequences.

Comment: Not sure if it is good for long term reliability, but you can power many chips through the protective clamping diodes on the IO pins. That'll obfuscate at least the power pins.

Comment: Include a few of [these chips](http://www.repeater-builder.com/humor/signetics-wom.pdf) to throw people off your trail.

Comment: "A little sandpaper will take the laser-etched marking off most ICs"  90% of the time I've seen this, I could still make out the numbers.  Be thorough.

Comment: @AdamDavis That link is broken; future readers might want to refer to [Signetics 25120](https://web.archive.org/web/20150421031254/http://www.repeater-builder.com/humor/pdfs/signetics-wom.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Google the phrase "ic remarking" to find many suppliers of this service.

Comment: btw, the 1-3W laser engraver from Aliexpress will remark IC's successfully. The $100 kind made of cd rom sliders. 500mW was struggling but worked (just). It is of course rather obvious, so probably doesn't acheive anything much..

Answer (score 3):

This question already has many answers, but there are some comments and answers that I would like to clarify.

---

### Removing Markings:

### Laser

Most of SMT guys can remove markings by the mean of laser. As some say it will still be possible to read the markings using special techniques though.

The advantage of the laser is the low cost, and fairly risk-free for the components.

Although the laser needs to be of a short wavelength to avoid damaging the chip.

### Grinding

My experience with grinding is that it's time-consuming and very easy to damage small components.

Definitely not an option for a large volume.

### Manufacturer

If you have large enough quantities, you can request them to change the markings on the chip. (but as you said your quantity is too low).

The bottom line is, if you have any fairly large quantities, the laser still remains the way to go.

---

### "Removing marking won't stop someone to clone the design"

This is true, some companies specialized in cloning designs can x-ray your chip and PCB, find the components, and the inner layer routing.

It is even possible to read and decode the program memory by this means.

Some also can decap the package with strong acid.

However, I can tell you that, unless you are doing something like the new Playstation 5, it is unlikely someone will go to that length to copy your design.

The argument that removing markings on the chip is useless, is the same as saying it's useless to lock your home door because anyway it would take 1 minute for a skilled locksmith to open it.

It is not the same amount of work to take a quick picture of a PCB and getting all the components used from the markings, compared to having to acquire the PCB and start decap all the chips with fumic acid.

It is all about increasing the men-hour cost required to copy a circuit. With markings, it is about 5 minutes based on a picture. With erased markings, that process would already be days or weeks. The point is to make the effort and cost not worth it.

---

### "hiding the numbers on chips is kind of a red flag that the product is really easy to clone, has nothing proprietary in it"

Good engineering is all about finding the simplest solutions to complex problems. Some solutions might be very simple, but the amount of work to get there may be trandemnous.

It is not because a circuit is simple, that there haven't been complex research, prototyping, and testing behind it.

Take a simple analog real-time, nano-second PID tuning loop for a rocket injector, it may only be a few components, but might be very complex to get it just right.

Often, an idea can simplify greatly a design. It may look trivial to the one that just looks at the finished circuit, but may not be trivial into the path to get there.

Einstein discovered E=mc2, a pretty simple formula right? But it took decades of work to get there.

Answer (score 2):

In small quantities, the markings can be removed with a rotary tool (like a Dremel tool) or sanded.  I've seen people do it even with a relatively straightforward circuit: a purely analog microphone preamp.  The circuit had about 4x ICs in SOIC-8.

By itself, removing the IC markings would deter simplistic attackers, and there are quite a few of them.  Combined with other obfuscations (protected firmware code, for instance) it will help deter or slow down more attackers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing them, you could simply hide them. A touch of an opaque epoxy on top. Or an entire blob to encase the IC. Or skip using dip package and use a smaller package, like WLP, or bare die and Chip On Blob it. That way it doesn't come with a label in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It is not difficult to search component libraries looking for part of the same style and size with matching power and ground pins. A simple product with little added value is exactly the kind of thing a cloner can make money at. The only way I know of to make a design hard to copy is to add value to it that isn't easily reproducible or is patentable and/or to iterate the product faster than the cloners can keep up.

Answer (score 0):

I've see following more or less effective methods to hide the part number of DIL ICs

- use ICs that have never been marked in the first place
- grinding the surface
- covering the surface with black paint
- bending the legs of the IC to the other side and inserting it upside down, so the top surface of the IC is facing the PCB; the unmarked "belly" is visible